# Laravel rest API returns user object in the post request

Tags: laravel, api

I created an API for login and register with the passport package in Laravel.  When I call the login url in Postman it returns `key_token`, `refresh token` and `expired_date`.
But I want also want to return the authorized user info in json (eg the username and pass and email).

I need this because the mobile phone team wants to integrate my web app.
Login controller method:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'username'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);

        $params = [
            'grant_type'=>'password',
            'client_id'=>$this->client->id,
            'client_secret'=>$this->client->secret,
            'username'=>request('username'),
            'password'=>request('password'),
            'scope'=>'*'
        ];
        $request->request->add($params);
        $proxy=Request::create('oauth/token','POST');


        return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

Comment: [Create Rest api with authentication](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/lumen-rest-api-authentication/). This might help you.

Comment: thk u it sound like a great resource ^^ @SaquibLari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to go is to create another URI that returns the authenticated user. This way, the client signs in and then performs a GET request to get the authenticated user. I like to simply set this URI to `/user`. Laravel side, you just have to create a route like this:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

By the way, this is how the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user) works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thk u it did helped me , yes its always better to give the user its own route @louisfischer :)